# convert a number to date in R

Tags: r, date, numbers, lubridate

I am doing an ifelse operation on two dates, and my resulting date comes as a number. My specific question is how to convert this number to a date format.

Below is the code that created this issue, the variable is fecha_epi_final:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
   temp_epi2 <- temp_epi1 %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate (b1 = force_tz(b1, tzone = "GMT"),
          b2 = b2 - days(1),
          fecha_epi_final = ifelse (is.na(b2) == T, b1 , 
                                    ifelse (b1>=b2 , b2 , b1)),
          mes_epi_inicio = floor_date(fecha_epi_inicio, "month"))
```

The str of fecha_epi_final is a number, in example: 1417564800

as a test data frame use:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
b1 <- c('2015-01-30' , '2014-12-17')
b2 <- c(NA , '2014-12-15')
temp_epi1 <- data.frame(b1 , b2) %>%
               mutate(b1 = ymd(b1) ,
                      b2 = ymd(b2))
```

Comment: by number you mean epoch time? you could use: date <- as.POSIXct(yournumber, origin="1970-01-01", tz="")

Comment: The underlying problem here is that `ifelse` doesn't preserve attributes. If you strip away the clutter and reduce this to a minimal example you'd have seen that. All I see here is a mess of pipes and dplyr that add nothing to clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply :

```
as.POSIXlt(1417564800, origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/New_York")
# [1] "2014-12-02 19:00:00 EST"
```